# Azure Media Services : Media/Video fails to decrypt on Safari/Edge browsers but works well in Chrome

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-media-player

So, we have been testing our Azure Media Services implementation on Google Chrome all this while (which has been working very well), and now found out that it doesn't work in Safari & Edge browsers!

It fails to decrypt the video.
Not sure what is the relationship between being able to decrypt and type of browser!

The encryption being used is DRM with PlayReady (CommonEncryptionCenc) & Widevine policy encryption, along with Azure Media Player.
I see that Safari only supports FairPlay, but Edge supports PlayReady. So, ideally it should work on Edge.

[image]

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it failing for you only on Safari and Edge on Mac OS?

Are you delivering HLS with CMAF or which URL format is failing for you?

We are aware of an issue in the AVframework for iOS recently that was preventing HLS with clear key being decrypted on iOS 13.5.  There was a regression in segment-encrypted fmp4 playback that got introduced in one of the iOS 13 updates.  It was fixed for iOS 13.6 beta by Apple.

UPDATE:
Based on your comments below - you may have been testing PlayReady on Edge for Mac OS?

Edge on Windows 10 support both Playready and Widevine
Edge on Mac supports Widevine only (I believe... checking for a definitive link to that support...)

Safari on Mac of course is FairPlay only.

You can test some DRM combinations using the AMP demo page here. Don't forget you need to use HTTPS!

https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F622b189f-ec39-43f2-93a2-201ac4e31ce1%2FBigBuckBunny.ism%2Fmanifest&widevine=true

Comment: Sorry, the encryption is actually DRM PlayReady & Widevine. Its failing on Safari/Mac OS and Edge/
 Windows.

Comment: Edge on Mac OS only supports Widevine DRM I believe. No PlayReady.

Comment: Edge on Windows 10 does support Playready - so that should be working for you there.

Comment: Edge on Windows 10 is not working. Will checkout with the amp link that you provided.

Comment: Make sure to hit that with https.